# Bypass cloudflare on java

Tags: java, web-scraping, cloudflare, http-status-code-403

I'm new in java and want to know if is there any way to bypass Cloudflare as in python (for example cloudscraper)
I need to fix a project that I inherited from a previous developer. There is a part, that login into the website and downloads the catalog, but it's given me an error [HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403] because the website has Cloudflare

```
 public Path checkCatalog() {
    try {
        Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(URL).execute();
        Map<String,String> cookies = response.cookies();
        Map<String,String> formData = new HashMap<>();
        formData.put("email","mail");
        formData.put("password","password");
        logger.info("Logging into Signeda");
        Jsoup.connect(URL).cookies(cookies).data(formData).post().connection().execute();
        response = Jsoup.connect(DOWNLOADS_URL).cookies(cookies).maxBodySize(0).ignoreContentType(true).execute();
        String date = DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date());
        Paths.get(DOWNLOADS + "/" + date).toFile().mkdirs();
        Path path = Paths.get(DOWNLOADS + "/" +date + "/catalog.xlsx");
        logger.info("Downloading catalog");
        Files.write(path, response.bodyAsBytes());
        return path;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```